# Maven configuration for Hibernate

Tags: maven-3

I tried configuring my Maven build with hibernate Validator So that I can validate my named queries during Buil rather during the launch of the application. Can any one help me with this.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest follow the link here to get started

http://hibernate.org/validator/documentation/getting-started/

1. Add dependency to your pom.xml

   org.hibernate
      hibernate-validator
      5.2.2.Final
2. if the application is not run in any application server, you'd better add an implementation of the Unified Expression Language

   javax.el
      javax.el-api
      2.2.4


      org.glassfish.web
      javax.el
      2.2.4
3. Run unit test to verify before launch application

Comment: @jiming My application is runnig on WAS. 
So my doubt is if i make a error in the structure of namedquery like in the below query


<sql-query name="aaa"> 
    <![CDATA[ 
       SELECT 
           status       FROM
           arun
       WHERE 
           customerID = :customerID AND status = :status
       ]]>
 </sql-query>